# how to create folder and sub-folder in a document library in SharePoint 2010 automatically when creating and new folder?

Tags: sharepoint

i'm new to SharePoint Server 2010 and i need to implement this scenario, i need to create a new product folder within a document library after this done sub-folders must be created within this folder with permissions, which means these sub-folders must have permissions to enable groups of users to view it for example or full control permissions.
is it possible to implement this scenario ?!!

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create EventReceiver project via Visual Studio 2010. Attach it to new item creation event. You should implement custom logic to check if this item is folder for a new product and then create needed sub-folders and set permissions for it programmatically.